# How to Plot3D when boundary of plot region doesn't return a number

Tags: plotting

I discovered an idiosyncrasy in how `Plot3D` works with an irregular region, **in Mathematica 10**: `Plot3D` first numerically evaluates the function at various points along the boundaries of the plot.  If no point returns a number, an empty plot is returned even if the function may return values in its interior.

---

Consider the following toy example:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  If[x == 0. || y == 0. || 1 - x - y == 0.,
    Indeterminate, 1]

g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 1;
```

And now try plotting

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]
(*Empty plot*)

Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]
(*Not empty plot*)
```

In the example above, `f` is like my real-case *extremely* complicated numerically-defined function; it chokes right on the boundary, and returns `Indeterminate` there.  But I'd like to generate a plot for it.

A **makeshift solution** is to slightly shift the domain specification: `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, .0001, 1}, {y, .0001, 1 - x}]`. Then a plot is displayed.  But I find this unacceptable, because I can't automate this in any reasonable way.

A **less makeshift solution** is to generate a `Table` of values, and then `ListPlot3D` the result: `data=Flatten[Table[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1, .05}, {y, 0, 1 - x, .05}], 1]; ListPlot3D[data]`.  This doesn't work so well because I lose the adaptive sampling algorithms of `Plot3D`.

Is there an option (documented or undocumented) that toggles how `Plot3D` works so that it tries a different set of points, before giving up?  What else can I try?

Comment: In my opinion, the example you present is too artificial to act as surrogate of your real problem. The  solution for example is simply to replace `f`` with `g`, but nothing so simple would probably work for the real case.

Comment: @m_goldberg `g` is unavailable.  It's in the question for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: `Plot3D[f[x, y] /. Indeterminate | Undefined :> f @@ Rescale[{x, y}, {0, 1}, {Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon,1 - Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 that's a good way to go.  I also found another possibility by using `Exclusions` (which works only if the boundary is known): `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, Exclusions -> x == 0]`

Comment: When I use `Exclusions`, I get an empty plot still.  (I tried that first, in fact.)  V10.4.1 (Mac).